# Why are Azure subscriptions at resource group level and also at app service plan level?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azureportal

I noticed subscriptions can set at resource group level (which seems very logic) and inside that, you can create an app service plan with another subscription.

Why do we have to set the subscription in the ASP since it already resides in a RG with a subscription?

[image: RG]

[image: ASP]

Comment: Notice that you haven't chosen a resource group yet for your app service plan. You're free to put it in any subscription you want. And you may then choose an existing or new resource group (and you can use the same resource group name in multiple subscriptions). You cannot deploy a resource from one subscription into a resource group of a different subscription.

Comment: Hello David, you say "You cannot deploy a resource from one subscription into a resource group of a different subscription." Then why do we have the options to choose any subscription for both RG and ASP?

Comment: The App Service Plan is unrelated to the resource group until you choose a resource group for it. And, once you choose the subscription for your app service plan, you are limited to either 1) a new resource group in that chosen subscription or 2) an existing resource group in that chosen subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be multiple Azure subscriptions within an Enterprise Agreement. Same resource groups name could be in multiple subscriptions. Subscriptions and resource group relationship is like below:

[image]

So, when you create web app, you need use specified subscription and exist or new resource group.

This [blog](https://www.credera.com/blog/credera-site/azure-governance-part-2-using-subscriptions-resource-groups-building-blocks/) maybe helpful.